Terminate test execution on browser freeze
I have test written in
Playwright +.net
specflow nunit
There is a problem in my app that freezes browser on certain condition. When test runs it, it is executed forever.
Is there any way to terminate the test after given time?

If you provide a [mcve] someone can help fix the real problem.

The NUnit TimeoutAttribute is intended for this situation. For example, use [Timeout(2000)] to terminate execution after 2 seconds.
However, in some situations, it may not be possible to terminate the application and your frozen browser could be one of them. Try it at any rate.
